# Signal Processing using Fourier Transform

Tags: signal-analysis, fourier-transform, homework, fourier, fourier-series

How can I derive the fourier transform of

```
                                   g1(t) = {A cos(2πfc t),−T/2 < t <T/2
                                            0,               elsewhere
```

and;

```
                                  g2(t) = cos(t), −∞ < t < ∞
```

my answer for `g1` is;

```
∫ g(t)exp(-j*2*pi*f*t)dt = ∫ Acos(2*pi*fc*t)exp(-j*2*pi*f*t)dt

   =∫ 1/2A (exp(j*2*pi*fc*t)+exp(-j*2*pi*fc*t))exp(-j*2*pi*f*t)dt

   =∫1/2A(exp(j*2*pi*fc*t)exp(-j*2*pi*fc*t)+∫1/2A(exp        (-j*2*pi*fc*t)exp(-j*2*pi*fc*t))

   =1/2A∫exp(-j*2*pi(f-fc)t) + 1/2A ∫exp(-j*2*pi(f+fc)t)dt

   =1/2A(f-fc)+1/2A(f+fc)
```

Comment: this looks like homework.  why not just plug into the formula for Fourier transform.

Comment: what do you mean? :/ yes this is homework. but i should derive the fourier transform of signals. how can I just plug it into fourier formula without deriving it?

Comment: and please learn to use $\LaTeX$ here.  put it in between a pair of dollar signs for in-line math and to put an equations out there prominently, put that in between a pair of double dollar signs.  for a $\LaTeX$ math reference, i use [the one at Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:Math).

Answer (score 2):

Hey it takes a lot of time in writing equations also I don't know to type in LATEX.so I am sending you image file for second one [image: answer for your second question]

Comment: @sagar When someone asks for help with homework, the tradition is to give them help/hints, but not fully solve the problem for them.

Comment: @Jim Clay ok sir i will keep it in mind :-)